# How do I use the filter function in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell

I have a haskell program to list all integers from [1..n] based on the input n.
I want to filter certain numbers based on a condition from it and display as a list. where and how can I use the filter function / condition?

According to haskell documentation:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

filter, applied to a predicate and a list, returns the list of those elements that satisfy the predicate; i.e.,

```
filter p xs = [ x | x <- xs, p x]
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You got it, pretty much. So the rest of the deal is designing the predicate function for your list. Assuming you already had a list called xs and a predicate function p, all you'd have to do is

```
filter p xs
```

Often, you'll see p defined as an anonymous, or lambda, expression, like so:

```
filter (\n -> n `mod` 2 == 0) xs
```

It is not necessary, and it might be helpful as a beginner to define named functions.

```
isEven n = n `mod` 2 == 0

evenListNumbers xs = filter isEven xs

evenListNumbers [1,2,3,4]
```

Which is this `[2,4]`.

So a predicate function for a given list filter takes a list element and returns a boolean value. If it's true, the element is retained (or added to the resulting list), and if it's false, it is passed over.

Comment: thanks! explained it very clearly. i understood how to filter even and odd numbers but what about filtering those numbers that can divide the input n? something like isDivisible n = filter [1..n] div n? what is the syntax for that? :S

Comment: You'd have to make a function along the lines of:

`isDivisible n p = n \`mod\` p == 0`

and use that as your predicate. Note that this function returns true if the remainder of dividing n with p is zero, and false otherwise. Be aware that the arguments are now in a slightly different order of what you want, so you might want to simply flip them in the definition for now, or use `flip`.

Comment: Getting errors, not sure where to define this predicate. i think I cannot use it in the same line as filter right? I want the program to get an input and list all its divisors. i want to know how the predicate is defined for this. thanks.

Comment: If you want to know how to find all the divisors for a given number, you should ask a new question with that specifically.

For finding all numbers in a list that are divisible by a given number, here's one way:
`filter (\n -> n \`mod\` 4 == 0) list`

Where list is the list you want to filter through. This function will return the list of numbers in list that are divisible by four.

Comment: Note that you could just as well have defined `divisibleByFour n = n \`mod\` 4 == 0` beforehand and have filtered with that as predicate, but you're right - not in the same line as filter.

Comment: great! that works perfectly. I did not know about using \n. but if i want to list all divisors that divide n itself i will have to use another variable right? also the list can be defined separately or can I simply put it [1..n] 

divisors x = filter (\n-> n `mod` x == 0) [1..x] doesnt seem to work. i know theres something wrong here

Comment: I guess I will ask a new question for this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you transform that condition into a predicate (a function returning `Bool`) and use it to filter the numbers.

For example, if you have to select only the odd numbers you can use `filter odd [1..n]`

Comment: You mean I have to define the predicate to be used with filter and is a function Int -> Bool that is passed as the first argument to filter. how exactly can I do this? that is my question. for example: how do i list all the divisors of an integer that I input.

Comment: Yes, you need a function of type `Int -> Bool`.

Your second example with listing divisors of input numbers cannot work in this way. Because from a single number you obtain a list of divisors, thus your function will have type `Int -> [Int]` which is not the same as `Int -> Bool`. In this case, maybe `map` or `concatMap` is what you wish.